# How do I manage Client-Side Encryption Data Keys using the Driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm trying to to implement the automatic client-side field level encryption feature (Available in MongoDB 4.2+ Enterprise) in my NodeJS project.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to use the 3.3 Node Driver (compatible with Mongo 4.2) to handle Data Keys.

This procedure is described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-client-side-encryption-data-keys/ and says:

> For guidance on data key management using a 4.2-compatible driver, see the documentation for that driver.

I tried searching on the Node Driver API docs (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/) about how to create and manage Data Keys but I was unable to find any of the methods. It does describe how to config the Client so that it uses Automatic Field Level Encryption, but this requires the data keys.

Answer (score 0):

> There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to use the 3.3 Node Driver (compatible with Mongo 4.2) to handle Data Keys.

You can see *some* usage snippets from the test in the driver code base [node-mongodb-native/test/functional/client_side_encryption](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/test/functional/client_side_encryption/prose_tests.js). This should be quite similar to how the `mongo` shell uses it. Using the example [Connect to a MongoDB Cluster with Automatic Client-Side Encryption Enabled](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Mongo/#connect-to-a-mongodb-cluster-with-automatic-client-side-encryption-enabled)
 on the `mongo` shell, you can use similarly in MongoDB Node.JS driver as below:

```
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(
    "<ATLAS_URI_HERE>",
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        autoEncryption: {
            keyVaultNamespace: "encryption.__dataKeys",
            kmsProviders: {
                local: {
                    // BASE64-ENCODED-96-BYTE-LOCAL-KEY
                    key: fs.readFileSync(MASTER_ENCRYPTION_KEY_PATH),
                }
            },
            schemaMap: {
                "hr.employees": {
                    "bsonType": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "ssn": {
                            "encrypt": {
                                "bsonType": "string",
                                "algorithm": "AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_512-Deterministic",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The example above is using `kmsProviders` for [Locally Managed Keyfile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption-key-management/#field-level-encryption-local-kms), please see [AWS KMS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption-key-management/#amazon-web-services-kms) for `kmsProviders` AWS Key Management Service.

See also the [Client Side Field Level Encryption Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide/) for an end-to-end procedure for configuring field level encryption using select MongoDB 4.2-compatible drivers (Click on the Node.JS tab to see examples in Node.JS)